# What is the first derivative of this function?

Tags: derivatives, newton-raphson

I am trying to implement a computer simulation of the algorithm described in this [paper](https://sci-hub.tw/10.1109/TSP.2007.909041).

I need to find a root using Newton's method. The problem is that I need to know the derivative of the complex modulus function and my math knowledge is not helping me a lot. The function is described at p. 4 of the PDF file:
[image]

I mention that the function contains complex values, excepting the absolute values (|.|) and lambda.

Can anybody help me with the first derivative of this function?

Comment: If it's the derivative with respect to $\lambda$, it's actually quite easy. I'd write an answer but it's a pain on mobile.

Comment: @MattSamuel Yes, it is with respect to lambda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't bother with
Newton's method.
You need to choose
an initial $\lambda$,
so choose two
and use the secant method.

A good discussion is here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secant_method

Comment: Thanks. The secant method works better than Newton's method.

Answer (score 0):

Write each term of the sum as $$f_j(\lambda)=\left|{a_j\over b_j+\lambda}\right|^2=
{a_j\over b_j+\lambda}
{\overline{a_j}\over \overline{b_j}+\lambda}$$
Then we just differentiate by the product rule:
$$\begin{align}
f'_j(\lambda)&=-{a_j\over b_j+\lambda}{\overline{a_j}\over (\overline{b_j}+\lambda)^2}-{a_j\over( b_j+\lambda)^2}{\overline{a_j}\over \overline{b_j}+\lambda}\\
&={-|a_j|^2\over|b_j+\lambda|^2}\left({1\over b_j+\lambda}+{1\over \overline{b_j}+\lambda}\right)\\
&={-|a_j|^2\over|b_j+\lambda|^2}\left({2\Re(b_j+\lambda)\over|b_j+\lambda|^2}\right)\\
&=-2|a_j|^2{\lambda+\Re(b_j)\over|b_j+\lambda|^4}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you. I've also tried the secant method and found that it actually converges faster and achieves better precision.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid nightmares and to keep the power of Newton method, compute the derivative by central finite differences.